# Why does brace initialization in C++ solve the problem of initialization of STL containers?

Tags: c++

I'm reading Effective Modern C++, in the section about brace initialization.

> Even  with  several  initialization  syntaxes,  there  were  some 
>   situations  where  C++98 had  no  way  to  express  a  desired 
>   initialization.  For  example,  it  wasn’t  possible  to directly 
>   indicate  that  an  STL  container  should  be  created  holding  a 
>   particular  set  of values (e.g., 1, 3, and 5)

Then he shows:

```
std::vector<int> v{ 1, 3, 5 }; // v's initial content is 1, 3, 5
```

Why wasn't it possible to do

```
std::vector<int> v(1,3,5)
```

before? How is the constructor of a class that accepts brace initialization different?

Comment: Take a look for yourself: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector.  In particular, the one- and two-argument versions are ambiguous for `std::vector<int>` because of (3) and (4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::vector<int> v(1,3,5)
```

It still isn't possible to do the above and that's because when you try to list initialize the standard expects that you use curly braces.

And for this

```
MyType obj1, obj2;
std::vector<MyType> v{ obj1, obj2 };
//std::vector<MyType> v = { obj1, obj2 }; //similar
```

if you consider the non-built in types it will become very obvious how list initialization works. In the case above the copy constructor comes into play twice for each element being initialized into the vector. First obj1 is copy constructed into a temporary and this temporary is then copied once again into the vector.

Consider the similarity in syntax to regular copy construction.

```
class Type {}

Type obj1;
Type obj2{obj1};
Type obj3 = {obj1};
```

Answer (score 7):

In order to implement

```
std::vector<int> v(1,3,5);
```

, the C++98 standard library implementers would have had to provide a constructor with an arbitrarily long argument list, and the presence of the constructor to set the number of elements of a given value, and the ability to change the *allocator* would have been a further complications. A maximum argument limit would have had to been agreed upon. It could have also been ambiguous if you wanted a vector of allocators! All this means the idea would have been objectionable.

The constructor facilitating modern day *list initialisation* uses a special initialiser list object.

Comment: It would have been very confusing `std::vector<int> v(1,3)`, vector of size 1 filled with 3s, or vector of {1, 3}. Similarly vector(1) means vector of size 1, or vector filled with value 1

Answer (score 6):

> Why it wasn't possible to do
>
> ```
> std::vector<int> v(1,3,5)
> ```

Because vector didn't have a constructor that would accept 3 elements.

It would not have been practical to define a constructor for every possible number of elements to initialise. Especially since some number of arguments are ambiguous with other constructors: Single integer constructs a vector of certain size, and one integer and one element copy initialises those elements.

The introduction of `std::initializer_list` and its special role in the extended list initialisation in C++11 made `std::vector<int> v{ 1, 3, 5 }` possible.

> How different is the constructor of a class that accepts brace initialization?

In case of vector, the declaration looks like this:

```
vector(std::initializer_list<T> init,
    const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```